# How can I generate a .jar that also includes javadoc in it using IntelliJ IDEA in a Gradle project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Im developing a library in Java using IntelliJ IDEA, also I use gradle for the project.
My problem is that when I build an artifact of my project the .jar file that is built does not include any of my javadocs and the names of the method arguments in interfaces are also lost. How can I generate a .jar that also includes javadoc in it using IntelliJ IDEA in a Gradle project?

Comment: You don't. First you change your compile options to include parameter names. Second, you create a *difference* jar file for the javadoc. If your code is open-source, you should then also create a third jar file for the source. Standard naming is that if your main (code) jar file is called `mylib-1.0.jar`, then the other two files are called `mylib-1.0-javadoc.jar` and `mylib-1.0-sources.jar`. [Answer by user6158055](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39059063/5221149) shows you how to that in Gradle.

Answer (score 2):

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}
```

Comment: While the specific code to add to a file is useful, some explanation of what it does or where exactly to add it would be of even more value.

Answer (score 1):

It is intended behavior. But there is a default 'javadoc' task which generates javadoc into 'build/docs' directory. So you can do this like:

```
task makeJavadoc (type :Jar, dependsOn: javadoc){
    from docsDir
    classifier='docs'
    description='Creates a Javadoc Jar'
}
```

The resulting javadoc has to be attached manually.